# can you please explain me this for loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I found this for loop in codepen .  Why he used for loop like this ? 4 parameters  ? His project is working . Please explain simple ,I am beginer . thank you

```
  timer = setInterval(function(){
    oCG.clearRect(0,0,1000,800);
    for(var i=0,l=aObj.length; i< l;i++){    <<<<======
      fnChange(aObj[i]);
      checkPeng(aObj,i);
    }
    
  },1000/60);
```

Comment: `,` isn't the same as `;` it still follows the general `for ([initialization]; [condition]; [final-expression]) statement` format of the for statement - just that there's two initialization statements, spearated by `,`

Comment: how many do you need

Comment: this is short cut for 2 for loops ?

Comment: In this particular case the reason is for performance. Detailed explanation here: http://simp.ly/p/mVLkH4

Comment: @Leftium why not just post that as an answer? that's a great explanation that shouldn't be buried in a comment link. -- **edit:** ah i see, because this question is closed. i'm voting to reopen. the linked duplicate does not include the context of using this as `for` loop initialization.

Comment: @tdy: Well, it started as an answer, but while I was writing the answer the question was closed as a duplicate. So I couldn't submit it. Vote to reopen this question! (And mark my original comment as helpful)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact is that he used a comma (`,`) in the first parameter (initialising variables) rather than a semicolon (`;`). This is used when declaring multiple variables at one time.

Answer (score 0):

`i=0,l=aObj.length;`  is one part(initializing values for loop) where `i` and `l` values are fixed

`i< l` is the condition

`i++` increment the value

therefore the `;` is used for separating the parameters and `,` is used for adding in the same parameter